# wants to replace the iframe based on Onlclick

Tags: javascript, iframe

I wants to replace the iframe, if user clicks on getPrice button again by selecting different input.I have written code and tried several things but nothing worked out. everytime I cant use document.body.appendchild(). My code is below. Please suggest here.

```
function getPrice()[ 
var ifrm  = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifrm.id = "frameID";
ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://40.85.176.227/invoke/Tier1ICLStd_New.Price/getPrice?CloudName=Azure East 
ifrm.setAttribute('align', 'right');
//ifrm.setAttribute('marginheight', '50');
ifrm.style.margin= "auto";
ifrm.scrolling="no";
ifrm.style.border= "0";
ifrm.style.margin= "0";
 //document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, document.body.firstChild);
//alert();
if(document.getElementById("frameID")==null)
{
 document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
 }
 else
 {
 alert("Else"); // I am getting control till here but what code to replace the existing iframe.
 //var item = document.getElementById("frameID").childNodes[0];
 item.replaceChild(ifrm,item.childNodes[0]);
 alert("test");
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

 //ifrm.parentNode.replaceChild(ifrm, ifrm);
}
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error : `function getPrice()[ ` should be `function getPrice(){`

Comment: `ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://40.85.176.227/invoke/Tier1ICLStd_New.Price/getPrice?CloudName=Azure East');` I suppose your code is like this?

Comment: You want to replace the complete Iframe or just its content ?

Comment: "[" is just typo while posting Question here.I want to replace iframe. replacing iframe and content is same for me both would work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the iframe content, you just need to use something like this :

```
function updateIframeSrc(newSrc) {
    document.getElementById("frameID").src = newSrc;
}
```

EDIT : Add exemple with HTML declaration to answer a comment.

```
<div class="frameClass">
    <iframe id="frameID" width="100%" height="1080" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
        src="http://svn.min.not/metasite/trunk/docs/README.md">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("iframeID").src = 'http://xyz'; but did not worked. did not happen any thing

Comment: humm... you id is "frameID", not "iframeID"... i edit my answer ^^.
And this work, i use it exactly as it is some web page.

Comment: WOW!!!!! thank you ..you caught it...I have tried this earlier also. but i think I did not catch this.... thankyou much.Worked for me too...but somehow this is not comming in center either left or right...

Comment: try removing your "align:right" if you want it to be centered. And then, i suggest you to put your iframe with a width="100%" attribute and place it into a div. Then, place you div where you want, it will be easier. Just a CSS issue now ;)

Comment: iframe in div in Javascript? I dont have any syntex in html body here. can you please provide sample in one line something...How to place into div?

Comment: oh you cannot edit your HTML at all ? So, you can build your page with javascript, even add div or other, but for this, i have no working exemple right now.
Can you edit your question and add the source of the result HTML page ?

Comment: I can edit Html. what I meant is : I have not written any code for this iframe in html, so where i will put div? can i put something like that.<div><iframe id>.....</div>

Comment: yes, exactly ! You can put your iframe in your HTML page, easier to play with CSS. I edit my answer to add you an exemple i'm using.

Comment: Thanks M.Be. anyway I got this working in other way.I put div and appended child of div...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery:

```
var i = 0;

var ifrm  = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.id = "frameID";
ifrm.setAttribute('align', 'right');
ifrm.style.display="none";

document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

function getPrice(){
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://40.85.176.227/invoke/Tier1ICLStd_New.Price/getPrice?CloudName=Azure East&token=' + i);
    ifrm.style.display = "inline";
    i ++;
}
```

Comment: I cant use JQuery, because server is maintained by Cloud Provider. please suggest alternative.