# Target iframe src inside ajax_injected chunk of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of code that is spit by oembed. then I need to target the src attribute of iframes and replace it with `data-src`.

Her's what I have currently:

```
embed_request = {
      url: url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        try {          
          var embed_html = (data.html).replace('src', 'data-src');
          $( "div#item"+number).html(embed_html);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    };    

$.ajax(embed_request);
```

The issue is that my replace() above changes too many `src` inside the chunk of code data.html

How can I tell via javascript or jquery here `var embed_html = (data.html).replace('src', 'data-src');` to only change the iframe's src it runs into inside the chunk of html code.

Today unfortunately my current code changes not only the below iframe src but also the src of `src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"`:

```
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/64567SDFFDFS/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0"  allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="849" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);"></iframe>
<script async="" defer="" src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

So I get in the final spitted view:

```
<iframe data-src="https://www.instagram.com/p/64567SDFFDFS/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0"  allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="849" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);"></iframe>
    <script async="" defer="" data-src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

How to only target the iframe's src ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are two examples of the html chunk code spitted by oembed

instagram

```
<div class="item active" id="item1">
<iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></iframe>
    <script async="" defer="" src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
</div>
```

Facebook

```
<div class="item " id="item2">

          <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_http" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="fb_xdm_frame_http" src="http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/0eWevUAMuoH.js?version=42#channel=f3e391184&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000" style="border: none;"></iframe><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" src="https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/0eWevUAMuoH.js?version=42#channel=f3e391184&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000" style="border: none;"></iframe></div></div></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-post fb_iframe_widget" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cocacolafrance/posts/1526674334016658" data-width="536" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=&amp;container_width=0&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcocacolafrance%2Fposts%2F1526674334016658&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=536"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 536px; height: 404px;"><iframe name="f2115553f8" width="536px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:post Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/post.php?app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2F0eWevUAMuoH.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Dfc155ce24%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Ff3e391184%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcocacolafrance%2Fposts%2F1526674334016658&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=536" class="" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 536px; height: 404px;"></iframe></span></div></div>
```

Comment: `(data.html).find('iframe').replace('src', 'data-src');`?

Comment: maybe look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761222/wants-to-replace-the-iframe-based-on-onlclick/40761290#40761290

Comment: @M.Be inseems they target it via the ID but I don't have the id in my codebase. I only have the oembed code which via ajax will spit the html. So i cant' target an id i don't know beforehand.

Comment: @Fran: no does not work: Ive tried "var embed_html = (data.html).find('iframe').replace('src', 'data-src');" I get data.html.find is not a function(…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the markup string to HTML elements (off the DOM) first, then find any iframe elements, replace their attribute(s), and add the whole thing to the DOM:

```
embed_request = {
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
    try {          
      $(data.html).filter('iframe').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('data-src', $this.attr('src')).removeAttr('src');
      }).end().appendTo("div#item"+number);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};    

$.ajax(embed_request);
```

Here's a mockup (replaced the ajax call by a function call etc.) to show that it's working:

```js
var number = 1,
    data = {html: atob("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")}; // this is the html provided by you, containing the iframe and script tag, but I had to base64 encode it, as otherwise the code snippet tool wouldn't let me insert it

(function (data) {
  try {          
    $(data.html).filter('iframe').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr('data-src', $this.attr('src')).removeAttr('src');
    }).end().appendTo("div#item"+number);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
})(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item1"></div>
```

Comment: I get ReferenceError: embed_html is not defined(…) via the catch(err)

Comment: sorry, it should have been `data.html` instead, of course. I edited the answer to correct that.

Comment: Thanks, but now i don't get any error, but the html spitted byoembed ajax request still has< iframe src...>and not <iframe data-src=...>. am trying to understand why. In my initial code (see my question), it did change ALL srcs:) here not enough

Comment: trying to understand why now

Comment: Sorry, another typo - we need to use jQuery's `filter()` instead of `find()`. if that doesn't work, it would be great if you could provide the contents of `data.html`, because it's hard to try to make this work without knowing the contents.

Comment: Or are those lines all you got in there?

Comment: Did not work. Will add 2 examples fo codes spitted by Oembed on which I don't manage to replace src by dat-src with your suggestion

Comment: I just updated my answer with an executable code snippet. After running it, you can inspect the iframe with your def tools and you'll see that the attribute is replaced correctly on the iframe.

Comment: updated again to use the correct (first) html snippet